# Understanding the Buddy Allocator

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

I have a conceptual doubt in understanding the way Linux Kernel manages Free blocks. Here is what I interpreted through reading so far.
The Buddy Allocator implementation is allocation scheme that combines a normal power-of-2 allocation.
At times when we need a block of size which is not available, it divides the large block into two. Those two blocks are Buddies, probably hence it is called the Buddy Allocator.
Through a source I learnt that an array of `free_area_t` structs are maintained for each order that points to a linked list of blocks of pages that are free.
Which I found in `<linux/mm.h>`

```
typedef struct free_area_struct {  
  struct list_head free_list;  
  unsigned long *map;  
} free_area_t;
```

The `free_list` appear to be a linked-list of page blocks? My question is, whether it is a list of Free pages or Used pages?

And `map` appears to be a bitmap that represents the state of a pair of buddies.

My question is How can it be a single-bit that holds the state bit for a pair of buddies? Because if, I use one of the block in a *Buddy-pair* to allocats, and the other left free, what would be the state then, and how is that managed to be stored in a single bit? Does it represent the entire block of the size of power-of-two, which can be divided in two parts when we need a block size which is not available, so the allocated half is *Buddy* of the other half which is free? If this is the case that half is being allocated and half remains free, then what will be status of `map` ? What if both are free? and what if both are allocated? How can be a binary value representing 3 states of a block?

**Edit:** After further reading, the first doubt is cleared. Which says: If a free block cannot be found of the requested order, a higher order block
is split into two buddies. One is allocated and the other is placed on the free list for
the lower order. So it is linked list of free pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` represents the state of a single memory block at the lowest level.

Comment: Agreed. But does it represent the entire block of the size of power-of-two, which can be divided in two parts when we need a block size which is not available, so the allocated half is *Buddy* of the other half which is free? If this is the case that half being allocated and half remains free, then what will be status of `map` ? What if both are free? and what if both are allocated? How can be a binary value representing 3 states of a block?

Comment: Added the same to the question body